# Correct way to go Login page after logout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using FlyOut, when I tapped the Logout (for example) the FlyOut menu is still showing when I screen swipe from left.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Logout" >
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate out:LoginPage}" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Is there any alternative to just show only the Login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this on top in your LoginPage.xaml

```
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
```

And maybe this

```
 Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
```